# How should i organize my ASP.NET Web API solution?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm starting a new ASP.NET Web API project. I admit, I have never been good at organizing my projects in my solution. I want to get better at this, hence the question.

First, the naming convention I plan to use is one I've found several places (blogs, MSDN, etc) and includes the CompanyName.ProductName.Component.

My confusion is around the projects within the solution. I have the proof of concept for the service working but everything is in one project. It works but this is bad for a variety of reasons and I want to separate the components. The project uses EF, interfaces for the data repository, a test project, business objects, and the my Web API controllers. How should I organize my solution and the various projects?

Answer (score 0):

There is no one one-size-fits-all answer for this question. However this is my default:

[image]

**Some additional notes:**

Although the project names for the web, core, and data are [productName].[layer], I change the default namespace and assembly name to be [company].[product].[layer]. I don't fully qualify the so that I can keep the path lengths down (The build will complain once you hit 256 characters in a path).

The model project usually has other folders too, such as \validation, \exceptions, etc... but I just wanted to illustrate that I usually put the interface for data access along side the model classes.

I do not change the default namespace or assembly name for the test projects because they aren't important to anything outside of the solution.

That being said, if my API is dead simple (only a couple controllers) I might go for one project for the API and one test project. If I do this, I add folders under the API for each logical layer (core, data, etc...).